# How should I batch-insert MySQL records that have dependents?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have business objects that can have "categories", so I'm using a simple table structure that looks like

```
objects:
|  id  |  name  |

categories:
| obj_id | cat |
```

Adding a new object along with its categories is simple enough:

```
INSERT INTO OBJECTS (name) VALUES ("This thing");
/* store the LAST_INSERT_ID() */
INSERT INTO categories values (lastId, "A category"), (lastId, "Another category"), ...;
```

The wrinkle is, I'm using JDBC batch queries to do the object inserts, so I'm not sure how to get the last-insert-id.  I need to bulk insert lots of objects but somehow keep the IDs from each so I can bulk-insert the related categories for each.

I thought about writing a stored procedure where I could pass the category as an array (nope, MySQL doesn't have an array type) or a comma-separated list (ditto for built-in string tokenization).  Is there an easier way?  Something like "INSERT INTO ... JOIN ..."?

Comment: You can use a transaction to group these together.

Comment: Right, of course, but the issue is that specifically in JDBC, I don't know how to do the parent insert, then do several child inserts using the parent ID, then repeat, without making each parent transaction separately.

Comment: The pattern is: `BEGIN; INSERT ...; INSERT ... (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...), ...; COMMIT` if you can be assured these will all run on the same connection.

Comment: OK, so, in Java, how do I do this in an injection-safe way?  I know I could just concat a bunch of query strings together and run that, but it's vulnerable if I don't use one of the sanitizing methods in the JDBC API...

Comment: There's [some examples](http://bobby-tables.com/java) on [this site talking about SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).